# PostgresQL, only contain not null values

Tags: sql, postgresql

I'm trying to output a query where if any of the following columns contains  NULL value (or for current sheet does not contain an empty string), then output the results, but it is still outputting results with null values. What am I doing incorrectly?

```
select * 
FROM   public._http_requests 
WHERE  ((_http_requests.currentsheet IS NOT NULL OR _http_requests.currentsheet != '') 
   OR _http_requests.session_id IS NOT NULL 
   OR _http_requests.http_referer IS NOT NULL)
```

Comment: Chage `OR` for `AND`

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Replace `OR` with `AND` to make sure all columns in `where` clause does not have any `NULL` value

```
SELECT *
FROM   PUBLIC._http_requests
WHERE  (_http_requests.currentsheet IS NOT NULL OR _http_requests.currentsheet != '')
       AND _http_requests.session_id IS NOT NULL
       AND _http_requests.http_referer IS NOT NULL
```

Comment: Oh of cource, I'm saying not null rather than null. My bad, sorry about that

Comment: The first `AND` still need to be `OR`

Comment: @BruceyBandit - It happens nothing to worry ;)